# Gohlke's numpy + mkl installation - Change MKL install directory on Windows

Tags: python, numpy, pip, intel-mkl, python-wheel

I've been trying to get a working fast numpy with BLAS on Windows, and so far, the only method that seems feasible is downloading the precompiled library with MKL from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy.

So far ok, but chekcing later `numpy.__config__.show()`, I see it points to directories that don't exist, such as `C:\program files (x86)\IntelSWTools`

I assume numpy is trying to place the MKL libraries in this directory, but I have no administration privileges for creating files in `C:\program files (x86)`.

Is there any simple way to use this numpy distribution and install the MKL libs in another directory? Such as a `pip install filename.whl --some_option_to_install_mkl_in_another_dir`?

(Windows 7 64bit, python 3.5.2)

---

**Already attempted:**

- Use `pip install <package> --user`: it seems to install everything exactly the same way as the same command without `--user`. (My default installation folder is aldready the user folder)
- User `pip install <package> --root <some_path>`: installs everything in the passed path, but Numpy config still points to `C:\program files (x86)\IntelSWTools`, and python cannot find numpy, even if I add `<some_path>` to both `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` environment vars
- Tried to create the `pip.ini` file, with the lines `[global]` and `target=E:\destination`. The destination folder remains untouched.
- Rename the wheels file to `zip`, find all files containing the IntelSWTools folder, change all these folders to one that I have access to. Make it a wheels file again and pip install. Absolutely no file appears in the folder I chose, but numpy config is pointing to that folder. -- This makes me wonder: **does this distribution really installs MKL?**

Comment: Does `pip install <package> --user` not fit your requirements?

Comment: Numpy `__config__` keeps pointing to `program files (x86)`. Should the mkl libraries fall elsewhere when I use `--user`?

Comment: Isn't `--user` the default already? Numpy goes to my user folders, but MKL seems not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Numpy+MKL` does not place (or try to place) MKL libraries in `C:\program files (x86)\IntelSWTools`. The **MKL runtime DLLs** necessary to use numpy+MKL are copied to `sys.prefix\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core` during installation with pip.

`C:\program files (x86)\IntelSWTools` is the location of the **MKL development files** (link libraries, header files, DLLs, documentation) that were used to build numpy+MKL. If you want to build other software from source that relies on MKL development files, you need to [download MKL from Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl).

Comment: Hmmm, thanks a lot :) -- But then.... is there a reason for my BLAS test from theano get such a terrible result? -- I get the test done in 20seconds, but from the table they present, it should take around 3 seconds.

Comment: Do you happen to know anything about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722188/tutorial-for-installing-numpy-with-openblas-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like this:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

I the above line:

```
$PREFIX_PATH ---- Change the path you want to specify.
package_name ---- Change the Package name with the desired package name or the wheel file.
```

On Windows, I tried the above and it is not working. But the below answer will work:

```
python.exe -m pip install --target=c:\data\ pandas
```

The pandas got stored in the `data` folder. Only the thing we need to do is we have to specify the path to our Python, so that it will fetch the proper library. You can go in the `data`   folder and run python. You will be able to access the library.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Target directory remained completely empty. The installation was done in the default folder (which is already the user folder). Numpy config still points to `C:\program files (x86)\IntelSWTools`. -- This question is not about just installing a package somewhere, it's about the package itself trying to place some files elsewhere.

Comment: @Daniel Hope this helps you. I have edited the answer.