# How to use non-mkl NumPy under Anaconda?

Tags: windows, numpy, anaconda, conda, intel-mkl

Anaconda Python distribution uses NumPy (and related packages) compiled against Intel-MKL lib, not "standard" NumPy. How can I use Anaconda with "standard" NumPy on a specific conda env? Using another Python distribution unfortunately is not an option at the moment. If relevant: I'm using Windows and Python 3.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create an environment in anaconda with numpy nomkl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656367/how-to-create-an-environment-in-anaconda-with-numpy-nomkl)

Answer (score 1):

There is a `nomkl` "meta-package" that installs packages without the MKL dependence. Simply install that package when you create the environment.

```
$ conda create -n nomkl python=3 numpy nomkl
Fetching package metadata .................
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /Users/user/miniconda3/envs/nomkl:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    ca-certificates: 2017.08.26-ha1e5d58_0
    certifi:         2017.11.5-py36ha569be9_0
    libcxx:          4.0.1-h579ed51_0
    libcxxabi:       4.0.1-hebd6815_0
    libedit:         3.1-hb4e282d_0
    libffi:          3.2.1-h475c297_4
    libgfortran:     3.0.1-h93005f0_2
    libopenblas:     0.2.20-h6c53463_3
    ncurses:         6.0-hd04f020_2
    nomkl:           1.0-0
    numpy:           1.13.3-py36_nomklh439e68b_0 [nomkl]
    openssl:         1.0.2n-hdbc3d79_0
    pip:             9.0.1-py36h1555ced_4
    python:          3.6.3-h47c878a_7
    readline:        7.0-hc1231fa_4
    setuptools:      36.5.0-py36h2134326_0
    sqlite:          3.20.1-h7e4c145_2
    tk:              8.6.7-h35a86e2_3
    wheel:           0.30.0-py36h5eb2c71_1
    xz:              5.2.3-h0278029_2
    zlib:            1.2.11-hf3cbc9b_2
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work:

Fetching package metadata ...........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - nomkl

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
  - http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
  - http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch

Comment: Searching for nomkl in Anaconda Cloud, only gives Linux and OSX versions. No Windows builds. Maybe there is some workaround for it...

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46656367/2449192 You can see there for options on windows