# Vectorising logsum using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to compute the `np.sum(np.exp(L))` where L is a long list of numbers which can be as high as 3000. np.float64 will overflow around exp(700). However, `np.logaddexp` is immune to overflow but only works for two elements.

I wrote the following recursive function to compute it for a list.

```py
import numpy as np
from smartprint import smartprint as sprint 

def logsum(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]
    return logsum([np.logaddexp(l[0], l[1])] + l[2:])


# odd length
l = [-10, 1, 2, 45, 100]

assert (logsum(l) == np.log(np.sum(np.exp(l))))
sprint (logsum(l))

# even length
l = [-10, 1, 2, 43]

assert (logsum(l) == np.log(np.sum(np.exp(l))))
sprint (logsum(l))
```

Output:

```py
logsum(l) : 100.0
logsum(l) : 43.0
```

Additionally,
`logsum([1,2,3,4,50000])` outputs `50000` as expected whereas the `np.exp` would overflow. Now, the problem is that my list L is huge and has upto 10 million elements and I need to compute the logsum at least 1000 times. So, I wonder if there is a way to vectorize using the `np.logaddexp` so that I can use it for a longer list instead of just two elements.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59850770/fastest-python-log-sum-exp-in-a-reduceat

Comment: Thanks @slothrop, yes the scipy version does the job for me, The question you referenced is aiming for something faster, which is definitely a niche requirement. Mine was more generic. The scipy solution works perfectly fine for my range of data values. and as expected is order of magnitudes faster than computing it in python explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on user: slothrop's comment, the `scipy` function for `logsumexp` works well and is already vectorised as expected. My recursive solution is no longer needed. Posting here for completeness.

```py
from scipy.special import logsumexp
logsumexp(l)
```