# How to speed up multidimentional Longsumexp and softmax using numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I want to calculate softmax/probability using multinomial logit while using `longsumexp` to avoid overflow. Using numba bring about 2-3x speedup. Can I do better here? Also when I use `fastmath=True` it does not seem to bring any speedup, so did I do write `numba` loops in a wrong way?

```
import numba
import numpy as np
def get_p_4d(a, lamda):
    m = a * lamda[:, None][:,None].transpose(0,3,1,2)
    c = np.max(m, axis=2)[:,None].transpose(0,2,1,3)
    aa = np.exp(m - c)
    logsumexp = c + np.log(aa.sum(axis=2)[:,None].transpose(0,2,1,3))
    p = np.exp(m - logsumexp)
    return p

@numba.njit()
def get_p_4d_nb(a, lamda, num_code, num_draw, num_action):
    p = np.empty((num_code, num_draw, num_action, 3))
    a = a.transpose(0, 1, 3, 2)
    for i in range(num_code):
        for j in range(num_draw):
            this_lamda = lamda[i,j]
            for k in range(num_action):
                p[i, j, k, 0] = a[i, j, k, 0] * this_lamda
                p[i, j, k, 1] = a[i, j, k, 1] * this_lamda
                p[i, j, k, 2] = a[i, j, k, 2] * this_lamda

                c = p[i,j,k,0]
                c = max(c, p[i,j,k,1])
                c = max(c, p[i,j,k,2])

                logsumexp = np.log(
                    np.exp(p[i, j, k, 0] - c) + np.exp(p[i, j, k, 1] - c) + np.exp(p[i, j, k, 2] - c)) + c

                p[i, j, k, 0] = np.exp(p[i, j, k, 0] - logsumexp)
                p[i, j, k, 1] = np.exp(p[i, j, k, 1] - logsumexp)
                p[i, j, k, 2] = np.exp(p[i, j, k, 2] - logsumexp)

    return p.transpose(0, 1, 3, 2)

a=np.ones((112,1000,3,3))
lamda = np.random.uniform(0., 1., size=112*1000).reshape(112,1000)
get_p_4d(a, lamda)
get_p_4d_nb(a, lamda, 112, 1000, 3)
```

Comment: You seems to use 64-bit FP numbers which are surprising for such a task. Are you sure you need them? `exp` and `log` functions are particularly expensive, especially on 64-bit FP numbers. Note that 32-bit FP numbers operations are also good to run the computation on GPU if you have one (though Numba only supports Nvidia GPUs).

Comment: If there is no speedup when using fastmath=True, it may make sense to ckeck if SVML is running correctly within Numba. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56939240/4045774 (The last part of the answer)

Comment: It still has no improvement after set SVML, and it prints 'not found'. Could it because I am using m1 mac? Sorry if this is naive question as I don't have cs background.

Comment: SVML is an Intel library for Intel hardware (though AFAIK it works on x86 AMD CPU). It might work using rosetta on M1 but not optimized for that and clearly not on ARM CPUs. The current code is not very SIMD friendly so I do not expect Numba (and more generally LLVM optimizers) to vectorize the `exp` and `log` calls. The timings matches with a scalar implementation on my i5-9600KF CPU. Numpy can uses an optimized implementation of `exp` and `log` on AVX-512 CPUs thanks to the help of Intel (which AFAIK added a part of the SVML directly in Numpy).

Comment: On CPU not supporting AVX-512 (e.g. x86-64 CPUs that are not recent, or ARM), the current implementation is not very optimized. The same is true for Numba without the SVML. Most libraries have inefficient math functions unfortunately on x86-64 already. This is even worst on the M1/M2 CPUs (supporting Neon). The support of the future SVE instruction set might improve that like AVX-512 did on x86-64 CPUs, but the support will take a long time (i.e. many years).

Comment: By the way, I tried few OpenCL implementations on x86-64 CPUs and my Nvidia 1660S GPU and results were far from being great (not much better than a naive parallel scalar Numba code which is clearly sub-optimal)... That being said, it was slow on GPU mainly because of data transfer (and kernel preparation overheads) while the M1 has a unified memory so it might worth it on the M1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try parallelize the task (I've also a little bit reduced the code using slicing `0:3`):

```py
@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def get_p_4d_nb_parallel(a, lamda, num_code, num_draw, num_action):
    p = np.empty((num_code, num_draw, num_action, 3), dtype="float32")
    a = a.transpose(0, 1, 3, 2)
    for i in numba.prange(num_code):
        for j in range(num_draw):
            this_lamda = lamda[i, j]
            for k in range(num_action):
                p[i, j, k, 0:3] = a[i, j, k, 0:3] * this_lamda
                c = np.max(p[i, j, k, 0:3])
                logsumexp = np.log(np.exp(p[i, j, k, 0:3] - c).sum()) + c
                p[i, j, k, 0:3] = np.exp(p[i, j, k, 0:3] - logsumexp)
    return p.transpose(0, 1, 3, 2)
```

---

Benchmark:

```py
from timeit import timeit

import numba
import numpy as np


def get_p_4d(a, lamda):
    m = a * lamda[:, None][:, None].transpose(0, 3, 1, 2)
    c = np.max(m, axis=2)[:, None].transpose(0, 2, 1, 3)
    aa = np.exp(m - c)
    logsumexp = c + np.log(aa.sum(axis=2)[:, None].transpose(0, 2, 1, 3))
    p = np.exp(m - logsumexp)
    return p


@numba.njit
def get_p_4d_nb(a, lamda, num_code, num_draw, num_action):
    p = np.empty((num_code, num_draw, num_action, 3))
    a = a.transpose(0, 1, 3, 2)
    for i in range(num_code):
        for j in range(num_draw):
            this_lamda = lamda[i, j]
            for k in range(num_action):
                p[i, j, k, 0] = a[i, j, k, 0] * this_lamda
                p[i, j, k, 1] = a[i, j, k, 1] * this_lamda
                p[i, j, k, 2] = a[i, j, k, 2] * this_lamda

                c = p[i, j, k, 0]
                c = max(c, p[i, j, k, 1])
                c = max(c, p[i, j, k, 2])

                logsumexp = (
                    np.log(
                        np.exp(p[i, j, k, 0] - c)
                        + np.exp(p[i, j, k, 1] - c)
                        + np.exp(p[i, j, k, 2] - c)
                    )
                    + c
                )

                p[i, j, k, 0] = np.exp(p[i, j, k, 0] - logsumexp)
                p[i, j, k, 1] = np.exp(p[i, j, k, 1] - logsumexp)
                p[i, j, k, 2] = np.exp(p[i, j, k, 2] - logsumexp)

    return p.transpose(0, 1, 3, 2)


@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def get_p_4d_nb_parallel(a, lamda, num_code, num_draw, num_action):
    p = np.empty((num_code, num_draw, num_action, 3), dtype="float32")
    a = a.transpose(0, 1, 3, 2)
    for i in numba.prange(num_code):
        for j in range(num_draw):
            this_lamda = lamda[i, j]
            for k in range(num_action):
                p[i, j, k, 0:3] = a[i, j, k, 0:3] * this_lamda
                c = np.max(p[i, j, k, 0:3])
                logsumexp = np.log(np.exp(p[i, j, k, 0:3] - c).sum()) + c
                p[i, j, k, 0:3] = np.exp(p[i, j, k, 0:3] - logsumexp)
    return p.transpose(0, 1, 3, 2)


a = np.ones((112, 1000, 3, 3))
lamda = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, size=112 * 1000).reshape(112, 1000)

x = get_p_4d(a, lamda)
y = get_p_4d_nb(a, lamda, 112, 1000, 3)
z = get_p_4d_nb_parallel(a, lamda, 112, 1000, 3)

assert np.allclose(x, y)
assert np.allclose(x, z)


t1 = timeit("get_p_4d(a, lamda)", number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit("get_p_4d_nb(a, lamda, 112, 1000, 3)", number=1, globals=globals())
t3 = timeit("get_p_4d_nb_parallel(a, lamda, 112, 1000, 3)", number=1, globals=globals())

print(t1, t2, t3, sep="\n")
```

Prints on my machine (AMD 5700x):

```
0.032106522005051374
0.010540901996137109
0.0014921170004527085
```